# Probleme with parameter queue_size in image_proc node

Tags: ros, roslaunch, image-proc, image-pipeline, parameter

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello everyone,

I try to change the size of the message queue in image_proc by raising the parameter ~queue_size in a roslaunch file:

```
<launch>
     .
     .
     .
  <node name="image_proc" pkg="image_proc" type="image_proc" ns="camera_pi"  output="screen" >
     <param name="queue_size" value="1" />
  </node>
</launch>
```

The parameter is raising correctly, it appears in rosparm list under the name : /camera_pi/image_proc/queue_size (seem correct to me ?). But this as no effect on the queue size of the node who remaining at the default size (5).

Any idea ?

Thanks

Edit : the image_proc node [documentation](http://wiki.ros.org/image_proc), see the section 3.0.1 Parameters, and the source code can be found [here](https://github.com/ros-perception/image_pipeline/blob/indigo/image_proc/src/nodes/image_proc.cpp#L58)

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/266708/probleme-with-parameter-queue_size-in-image_proc-node/) by [lettuce](https://answers.ros.org/users/30600/lettuce/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2017-07-18

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The `~` character in the parameter in the [documentation on the wiki](http://wiki.ros.org/image_proc) isn't part of the parameter name. It just indicates that the parameter is private. In roslaunch, you specify a private parameter by putting the `<param>` tag inside of the `<node>` tag.

Your launch should look like this:

```
<launch>
     .
     .
     .
  <node name="image_proc" pkg="image_proc" type="image_proc" ns="camera_pi"  output="screen" >
     <param name="queue_size" value="1" />
  </node>
</launch>
```

For more information on parameter namespaces, see [the wiki page on Names](http://wiki.ros.org/Names).

---

Originally posted by [Ed Venator](https://answers.ros.org/users/2636/ed-venator/) with karma: 1185 on 2017-07-21

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [lettuce](https://answers.ros.org/users/30600/lettuce/) on 2017-07-24**:
Thank for the answer and the info, but i already tried without the `~` and i got the same result...